# How to monitor message (file) processing steps in Spring-Integration

Tags: spring-integration

Spring integration really helps us a lot during application integration, it make us more focus on flow design.

However, we want to log all file processing steps and  use log analytic tools to check how one specific file(message) been processed.

Question is how to log a grouping id for each message in order to group them for checking by another logging anlytic tools?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to turn on [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) for your application. This way in the end of flow you can extract such a `MessageHistory.HEADER_NAME` with all the traveling information for the message.

Otherwise you really don't have choice unless to add some business header in the beginning of the flow and parse logs for such a common key.